# What happened at the end of the Super Mario Bros film?

Tags: super-mario-brothers, super-mario-bros-1993

The Super Mario Bros film ended on a cliff hanger…

What happened,  and what if any were the plans for a sequel?

Comment: Obviously they have to beat all the Koopa kids

Comment: The real cliffhanger question at the end was, "how the hell did this movie get made?"

Comment: My nostalgia for the film is two great to hear you,  @phantom42

Comment: the actors who played Mario and Luigi were reportedly drinking alot on set....

Comment: Why did you have to remind me of this? I would prefer to remember Bob Hoskins in better movies, like *Spice World* or *Garfield*.

Comment: @phantom42 - Mushrooms. 'nuff said.

Comment: @KSmarts - not "Who Framed Roger Rabbit?", though? That's a classic!

Comment: At the end, everyone deeply regrets the time wasted watching the movie.

Comment: Who could’ve imagined that in adapting a kid’s videogame, the director of the critically acclaimed The Killing Fields and The Mission, along with the executive producer on Chariots of Fire and a script written by the guy who did Rain Main were a bit out of their element.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

There’s an online comic [*Super Mario Bros 2*](http://smbthecomic.com/) which continues the story. From the [about page](http://smbthecomic.com/about/):

> In 1993 Lightmotive Pictures released Super Mario Bros. The Movie, a live-action adaptation of the popular video game series. The film ended with a sequel hook which went unexplored — until now.
>
> **Following discussions with original writer Parker Bennett, Steven Applebaum and Ryan Hoss have scripted a new adventure that continues right where the film left off.** Join Mario, Luigi and Princess Daisy as they explore new locations and creatures inspired by the games, yet adapted in the film’s unique cyberpunk style.

According to [their FAQ page](http://smbthecomic.com/about/faq/), it picks up the film’s storyline, is based on what would have happened in a sequel, and thus can be considered canon:

> **Is it canon?**
>
> Yes! Steven and Ryan worked with original writer Parker Bennett on outlining the project. Parker discussed in detail the backstory for the parallel world as well as possible ideas for the unproduced sequel, resulting in a groundwork for our team to script a new story. This adventure is as close to what would have made it on film.

I haven’t read the comic, so I can’t tell you what happens, nor have I found an interview with the original Parker Bennett confirming its canonicity, but it seems legit.

Comment: It's like Comicon and Christmas all at once.